# can't dismiss ProgressDialog (using BroadcastReceiver)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, progressdialog, dismiss

my problem is:
I want my application to block buttons or whole activity when there is no internet connection and unblock them when internet connection is back. I'm using BroadcastReceiver to check internet in main activity and it works well:

```
public class MainActivity extends BroadCast {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}

// code
}
```

To block MainActivity I'm using ProgressDialog with method setCancelable set to false. 
BroadCast Activity:

```
public class BroadCast extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

            if(currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
                BlockActivity(true);
            }
            else {
                BlockActivity(false); 
            }
        }
    };

    public void BlockActivity(Boolean connected)
    {
        final ProgressDialog pausingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Application waiting for internet connection...");

        if (!connected)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pausingDialog.show();
            pausingDialog.setCancelable(false);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pausingDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pausingDialog.dismiss();        
        }
    }
}
```

Toast information works good, but the problem is with ProgressDialog. It shows up when internet connection is gone, but it don't want to disappear when internet connection is back. How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a global reference to your dialog so you don't keep recreating it. You should also use primitive types (`boolean` instead of `Boolean`)where possible and adhere to Java naming conventions (camelCase).

```
ProgressDialog pausingDialog;
public void blockActivity(boolean connected)
    {
        if (pausingDialog == null){
            pausingDialog = new ProgressDialog (this);
            pausingDialog.setMessage ("Application waiting for internet connection...");
        }

        if (!connected)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pausingDialog.show();
            pausingDialog.setCancelable(false);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            pausingDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pausingDialog.dismiss();        
        }
    }
```

Comment: @user2129253 You're welcome :-) Since your issue is resolved, accept this answer by clicking the [hollowed out checkmark so it turns green](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/202881).

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Code In Kotlin**

```
var pausingDialog:SweetAlertDialog?=null
fun blockActivity(connected: Boolean,context: Context) {
    if (pausingDialog == null) {
        pausingDialog =SweetAlertDialog(context, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE)
        pausingDialog!!.titleText = "Application waiting for internet connection..."
        pausingDialog!!.setCancelable(false)
        pausingDialog!!.setConfirmClickListener{
            var MyReceiver: BroadcastReceiver?= null;
            MyReceiver = com.example.myrecharge.Helper.MyReceiver()
            context.registerReceiver(MyReceiver, IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))
        }
    }
    if (!connected) {
        Toast.makeText(
            context,
            "Disconnected",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        pausingDialog!!.show()
        Log.d("@@", "onReceive: 1")


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
            context,
            "Connected",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show()
        pausingDialog!!.dismiss()
    }
}
```